# Is there an ortools function on python to ask for a precise number of solutions?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, or-tools

I found the AllSolutions() method but this is an enormous loop in my case (asking for all the different sudoku possible (with no initial numbers)) and i would like to know if it is possible to ask for only like 10 solutions and not all of them ? 
Or I noticed that when asking for only one solution or tools gives us the same solution over and over again, isn't it possible to ask for another ? 
Thank you, i hope i am clear enough …

Comment: I hope this is cleare to or-tools-users. To me it's not.
Please provide more context next time.
If you just want to limit the amunt of solutions, this should help: https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_tasks#solution_limit

Comment: Off-topic warning: what you are doing will lead to (strong) non-uniform bias which is hard / non-trivial to combat. Maybe you should take a step back to reason about your task and what exactly you want. Uniform-sampling of combinatorial-problems is very hard. It seems, there is literature targeting uniform sudoku-sampling available. Additionally, there is literature about SAT-based uniform-sampling (and imho some are usable with ortools too; e.g. xor-sampling). Easier might be a combination of rejection-sampling + ortools as oracle. But well... It all depends on your goals. Analyze your sols!